# Why do queues in a queue family in Vulkan need priority if we can't distinguish between them?

Tags: hardware, gpgpu, vulkan

As asked in the title. My main point is "why", as in what's the benefiting factor in such logical structure for queues and queue families.

Do chip/card makers actually etch multiple independent queues onto their chips? That are at the same time separately distinguishable?

Does implementing separate processing units/streams provide any benefit to implementations? And by extension, does it retroactiely benefit older APIs such as OpenCL?

<s>I've observed an interesting fact: that in my "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100B CPU @ 3.60GHz" Mac Mini, there are 2 GPUs listed in "vulkaninfo.app" (from LunarG SDK).</s> My bad, the app linked against 2 libMoltonVK.dylib (1 in "Contents/Frameworks", 1 in "/usr/local/lib").

Comment: "*if we can't distinguish between them?*" But you *can* distinguish between them. So your question is kind of moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Why" is not a great question for SO format. It leads to speculation.

The queues are distinguishable in Vulkan. They each have their index with which they can be distinguished. Keep in mind they are rather a driver thing. Even when the driver has more queues, even single one typically can use all the GPU's computing resources.

Furthermore Vulkan specification does not really say what should happen when you supply a specific priority value. It is perfectly valid for driver\GPU to ignore it.

Chip makers do have compute units that are independent. They can theoretically execute different code from each other. But it is not usually advantageous. In the usual work rendering some regular W × H image, it saturates all the compute units with the same work.

Answer (score 0):

Why: because you can submit different types of work that're of different importance, and you can give a hint to the Vulkan implementation what you want to be done first-most.

Everything else in the question are pointless:

> Do chip/card makers actually etch multiple independent queues onto their chips? That are at the same time separately distinguishable?

Not necessarily, those may be logical queues that're time-sliced.

> Does implementing separate processing units/streams provide any benefit to implementations? And by extension, does it retroactiely benefit older APIs such as OpenCL?

No, a contemporary API called Metal (from Apple) don't have a queue count or the concept of queue family at all.